# How do i add this to rjs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rjs

I have this command which i know is a bit off syntactically

```
 page << "$('.places').append('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'contact', :locals => {:contact => @contact, :something => @something, :checked => false, :sale => @sale.item.to_s})) %>');"
```

this is the basic call that i need to make but I know the syntax is wrong for a js.rjs file....is there a way to convert this to that format

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Using prototype (Rails 2.3)

```
page.select(".places").each  do |element, index|
  page.insert_html :bottom, element, :partial => 'contact', :locals => {:contact => @contact, :something => @something, :checked => false, :sale => @sale.item.to_s}
end
```

Using jQuery (Rails 3)

```
$(".places").append("<%= escape_javascript render 'contact', :locals => {:contact => @contact, :something => @something, :checked => false, :sale => @sale.item.to_s} %>");
```